# Do until cell value between -1 and 1

Tags: excel, vba

Me again... Working on the same project with a different problem!

I have 3 values (calculations but I just need the resulting value), only 1 of which I need to insert into the FIRST cell of my amortization schedule. When the value is inserted, the LAST cell should then equal 0 or close to it.

Currently, my loop just goes forever and ever until the end of eternity.

```
Dim LastCell As Range: Set LastCell = Destination.Offset(9, 12).End(xlDown) 'Last cell of
'the amort schedule, should be 0 or close to it at end of term. Destination is a named cell,
'I'm getting better at avoiding ActiveCell!

Dim PV1 As Double: PV1 = Destination.Offset(0, 12) '2440754.76
Dim PV2 As Double: PV2 = Destination.Offset(1, 12) '2400379.97 This is the value in my 
'current scenario that I need, but it may not always be the case
Dim PV3 As Double: PV3 = Destination.Offset(2, 12) '2429942.76

Dim UseCalc As Range: Set UseCalc = Destination.Offset(9, 12) 'First cell of the amort schedule

Do Until (LastCell.Value >= -1 And LastCell.Value <= 1)
    UseCalc = PV1
    UseCalc = PV2 'When it gets to this point, I can see the value in LastCell
    'becomes 1.0000000000001839362E-02 which SHOULD trip the between -1 and 1 threshold,
    'but I'm sure something in the variables I'm setting are going wacky
    UseCalc = PV3
Loop
```

I assume the combination of variables I'm using is not correct and this is why it's not tripping the "Do Until", but I've tried every sensible combo I can think of. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim LastCell As Range, UseCalc As Range
Dim arrPV(1 to 3) As Double, x as long

Set LastCell = Destination.Offset(9, 12).End(xlDown)
Set UseCalc = Destination.Offset(9, 12)

arrPV(1) = Destination.Offset(0, 12) '2440754.76
arrPV(2) = Destination.Offset(1, 12) '2400379.97
arrPV(3) = Destination.Offset(2, 12) '2429942.76

for x = 1 to ubound(arrPV)
    UseCalc.Value = arrPV(x)
    If LastCell.Value >= -1 And LastCell.Value <= 1 then exit for
next x
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! I appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the loop scope, your `LastCell` value is based upon `PV3`, not `PV2`. Step through your macro and check the values of `UseCalc` (`UseCalc.Value`), `PV3` and `LastCell` (`LastCell.Value`).

In addition, you do not change the values of `PV1`, `PV2` or `PV3` during the loop, so each loop will have exactly the same effect. With nothing changing, your loop condition won't trigger.

Comment: I do step through and watch those variables, and the values are what I listed above. I watch UseCalc.Value cycle through all of the PV values and watch LastCell get to the value of 0.01 (albeit in scientific notation). In the excel sheet, I can watch this happen as I do it. The problem is that the "do until" doesn't stop at PV2 where everything looks golden, it continues on to PV3. Am I misunderstanding the Do Until purpose? When the "until" is met, does it not end the loop?

Comment: @Sarah the entire code block within the loop is executed. The `Do Until` doesn't stop at `UseCalc = PV2`, even if that satisfies the condition of `>=-1` and `<=1`.

Comment: @BigBen Ah, that explains it! Would an If Then statement be better suited?  I wanted to avoid writing an unnecessarily long argument, but if it's necessary then it's necessary. Or is there a better way?